# Vaadin tables inside a table, scroll issue

Tags: vaadin

I have a complex component with two tables. Now I have to put several of these in another table. The problem is when I try to scroll inner tables, the outer table scrolls.
Do you have any idea why/how this happens? Any suggestion to overcome this is highly appreciated.

**Note** 
Inside component's tables have implemented click listeners, outer one hasn't.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Care to show a printscreen? Does it scroll wrongly when using the scrollbars, or only when using the mouse scroll?

Comment: Mouse scroll is working fine. The issue occurs when using scroll bars.
I don't know if I can share a screenshot, I'll share one without sensitive info. :)

Comment: @AndréSchild screenshot added. Sorry I had to remove inner contents.